# How do I construct a probability distribution where none of the mass lies within one σ (standard deviation) of the mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

> Does this condition satisfy that the probability distribution where
> none of the mass lies within one σ of the mean?
>
> $$P(X=0) =0.5$$
> $$P(X=1) =0.5$$

Comment: Hint: what is the $\sigma$ of the given distribution?

Comment: @MattiP.  σ  represents the standard deviation

Comment: Yes, correct. Do you know its numerical value in this case?

Comment: You need to use *within* to represent "strictly less than", as all the probability mass lies exactly one standard deviation from the mean

Comment: @MattiP. In question, the value of σ is not given. We just need to find a probability distribution where none of the mass lies within one σ of the mean.

Comment: Yes I know. But it's possible to **calculate** $\sigma$ in this case ... Perhaps you can find out how to do it? Once you know it, it's a mere mental calculation ...

Comment: @MattiP. σ=|a-b|/2

Comment: @AdilAbid Where did you find that equation? Anyway, since we only have two possible values for the outcome, it's better to use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Definition_of_population_values

Comment: @MattiP. A probability distribution where the whole of the mass lies exactly one σ from the mean. If so, the discrete distribution P(X=a) = P(X=b) = 0.5 meets our requirements. In this case, the mean is (a+b)/2 and σ=|a-b|/2. Did you get my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $$\mu = E(X) = 0P(X=0) + 1(P(X=1) = 0 + 1(1/2) = 1/2,$$ and that $\sigma^2 = Var(X) = 1/4,$ so that
$SD(X) = \sigma = 1/4.$ [You are right that the value of $\sigma$ is not "given," but nothing is stopping you from computing it from
the information given.] The random variable $X$ has a Bernoulli distribution with $p = 1/2.$

Then the open interval with endpoints $\mu \pm \sigma$ is
$(0, 1).$ So $P(0 < X < 1) = 0.$ as in @Henry's Comment.